# SQL Server 2012 Database restore error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to restore a database backup from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012 Standard. It keeps failing with the error seen here: http://screencast.com/t/UWC58GrVnWI

The web server is: Windows Server 2012

1. I tried renaming the file.
2. I tried to restore on another server
       on SQL 2012 and it worked fine
3. I tried to restore on another
       server on SQL 2008 R2 and it worked fine.

Considering above symptoms, I strongly feel the database .bak file is good. It only fails on this web server. What might be the reason?

Comment: The account you are using to restore this database does it have permissions on the location where you are restoring this database??

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message you will find out that it is clear - the location is invalid. Now, if you check the path of folders and know the basics of how windows file systems work.... guess what, you find out that this is exactly true.

Fix the location. Done.